# gpg-agent socket do not persist between session in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnupg, 17.10

I upgrade to 17.10 yesterday and now i had trouble with gpg-agent, it seems now **/run/user/PID/** is clean when user logout and so the gpg-agent socket disapear and when i re-log i can't connect to the running gpg-agent daemon.

I compare with a server in 17.04 and **/run/user/PID/** persist between session so is it a bug with 17.10 or a new behavior ? if so what is the new correct way to get a gpg-agent daemon who persist between session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable lingering prevent systemd to clean **/run/user** folder after logout and resolve my problem

```
loginctl enable-linger USER
```